# NodeJS Async series not working sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm

I have the below code,

```
    var async = require('async'); var rest = require('restler');

    async.series([
        function(callback){
           rest.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json').on('complete', function(result) {
              if (result instanceof Error) {
                console.log('Error:', result);
                this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
              } else {
                console.log(result);
              }         });
            callback(null, 'one');
        },
        function(callback){
            console.log('2nd function');
            callback(null, 'two');
        }
        ],

// optional callback
        function(err, results){
               // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
               console.log(results);
        });
```

I am expecting output like this,

```
{ errors: [ { message: 'Bad Authentication data', code: 215 } ] }
2nd function
[ 'one', 'two' ]
```

But am getting the below output,

```
2nd function
[ 'one', 'two' ]
{ errors: [ { message: 'Bad Authentication data', code: 215 } ] }
```

Rest request output always coming at last.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function(callback){
       rest.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json').on('complete', function(result) {
          if (result instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Error:', result);
            this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
          } else {
            console.log(result);
             callback(null, 'one');
          }
       });
    },
```

`rest.get` is an asynchronous function. By calling it, you fire it off and continue blindly. Move your callback into `rest.get`'s callback function.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't think this way, is there way I can identify which are asynchronous calls and which are synchronous calls?

Comment: Generally, if the call requires a callback function, then it is asynchronous.

Comment: There are very few synchronous calls in node and they are usuaully xxxSync() method name.  The area where you use the sync methods is in the file system module.

Comment: Yeah, I think I should understand the concepts in a better way. Thanks for the information.